# oracle sql replace "in" to advance query

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a table. I have to query a sql such as:

```
select * from user1 where user1.id in(1,11,111)
```

"1,11,111" are the already knowed value where from the session.

Now I want to replace the `in` to advance the performance, but the `exists` cannot do it.

If you know how to do, please tell me know. Thanks!

Comment: The `in` should be fine, from a performance perspective.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate the list of values programmatically? What exactly do you want to change and why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OR`

```
SELECT *
FROM user1
WHERE user1.id = 1
OR user1.id = 11
OR user1.id = 111
```

Comment: You can do this, but why would it be any better?  This is what IN means, and the optimizer can potentially transform one form of the query into the other.

Comment: This is exactly the same query in terms of performance and how it is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `IN` operator is just fine and does exactly what it is meant for. The **optimizer** will internally **transform** the query into `OR` conditions. For sake of simplicity and less code to parse, the IN will shorten the query and easy to write instead of multiple OR statements.

The **explain plan** will clearly show that the **filter** applied is transformed into multiple OR for the IN clause.

For example,

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM emp WHERE deptno IN(10,20,30);

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |    13 |   481 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    13 |   481 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("DEPTNO"=10 OR "DEPTNO"=20 OR "DEPTNO"=30)

13 rows selected.
```

So, as you can see, `WHERE deptno IN(10,20,30)` is interpreted by optimizer as `"DEPTNO"=10 OR "DEPTNO"=20 OR "DEPTNO"=30`